# Does Stargate REST API support LIMIT clause?

Tags: cassandra, cql, stargate-oss

Does Stargate rest api support LIMIT query in Cassandra (DSE 6.8)?

```
Select * from table LIMIT 100;
```

If any, can you provide me an example?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Stargate REST API equivalent of `LIMIT` is the `page-size` query parameter documented here

https://stargate.io/docs/stargate/1.0/attachments/restv2.html#operation/getRows